# Get temperature of battery on android

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, temperature

How do I get the temperature of the battery in android?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
private class mBatInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{ 

    int temp = 0;

    float get_temp(){
        return (float)(temp / 10);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
    }

};
```

then define in your Variable declarations:

```
private mBatInfoReceiver myBatInfoReceiver;
```

and in onCreate:

```
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) { 
        super.onCreate(b);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ...
        // Add this

        myBatInfoReceiver = new mBatInfoReceiver();                                     

        this.registerReceiver(this.myBatInfoReceiver,
                              new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

     }
```

later call e.g in a OnClickListener()

```
float temp = myBatInfoReceiver.get_temp(); 

String message = "Current " + BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE + " = " +
                  temp +  Character.toString ((char) 176) + " C";
```

Comment: What's better about this solution than the much shorter one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21356233/7483211

Answer (score 13):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

public static final String EXTRA_TEMPERATURE
Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer containing the current battery temperature.

Comment: What is ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED about? Do I have to lunch an intent to get the temperature? Do I have to listen to some system wide intent?

Comment: @Christian: You do not need to register an actual `BroadcastReceiver` if you do not want to. Call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`, and it will return the last Intent that was broadcast for this action. Use the `EXTRA_TEMPERATURE` extra to get the value you seek.

Comment: Great post, I done some sample app to read the temperature and it works great but I can't not figured out what is the unit of the result here is my post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716054/getting-the-battery-temperature-and-unit-of-the-result)

Comment: they should really make the "null" version a separate method with a different name rather than overload it's meaning.  Thanks for the comment though I didn't even think to look it up there.

Comment: @Select0r link is broken

Answer (score 9):

```
    public static String batteryTemperature(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));    
        float  temp   = ((float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0)) / 10;
        return String.valueOf(temp) + "*C";
    }
```

Comment: Does this do the same job as the accepted answer? If so, why is it so much shorter? Has it all been inlined? Would be great to have a quick description. Thanks!

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer because it is a sticky intent/sticky broadcast, for more detail 
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490913/what-is-a-sticky-broadcast

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView BatTemp;

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) 
        {

          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);

      };

@Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle b) 
      {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        BatTemp = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the static int [BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_TEMPERATURE)

Comment: According to the documentation EXTRA_TEMPERATURE happens to be a String. It's also static and therefore will always be "temperature".

Comment: True, but the doc also says: "Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" - so your static String is just the key to get the temperature from ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.