# how to get battery temperature in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get temperature of battery on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android)

Hi

I want to get battery temperature in android. How can i achieve the same? Is there any api available? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html) how to register to battery changes. Using the extra value (`EXTRA_TEMPERATURE`) you can get the temperature.

In short (taken from the link above and modified a bit):

Declare broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
      int temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
      ....
    }
  };
```

and in `onCreate`, add:

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```