# get google glass heat programmatically

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

As I am doing live streaming in google glass, how can get the google glass heat programmatically and shows alert to the user when heat reaches some predefined threshold value?

Answer (score 3):

You can check battery temperature and battery health:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        int temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
        int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "temperature " + temperature);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "health " + health);
    }
};
```

In onCreate:

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

On Android devices, we can get [BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT) when the device's overheating.

Please see:

1. [how to get battery temperature in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974063/how-to-get-battery-temperature-in-android)
2. [How is the Android battery health determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098979/how-is-the-android-battery-health-determined)

Answer (score 1):

There is no temperature API in Google Glass that you can access.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Glass in a while so maybe it's changed, but this was a built in feature a while back. If you it got too hot you'd receive a warning at the OS level.