# How to get battery temperature updated in every 10 seconds in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get temperature of battery on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android)

I am new to android, making an app which shows the battery temperature of the android updated in every 10 seconds...please help me out

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue_tooth);


        LinearLayout big = new LinearLayout(this);
        big.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



    LinearLayout small[]= new LinearLayout[5];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    { 
        small[i]= new LinearLayout(this);
    small[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     temp = new TextView(this);
     small[i].addView(temp);


       volt= new TextView(this);
      small[i].addView(volt); 

        big.addView(small[i]);
    }
        setContentView(big);

        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

      }

      private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
            int voltage= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);
            temp.setText("Temperature="+String.valueOf(temperature) + "%");
          volt.setText("   " +"Voltage="+String.valueOf(voltage) + "%");
        }
      };
```

I am getting battery temperature and voltage but I'm unable to update this for every 10 seconds

Comment: You must show your efforts. Until then, I'm afraid you won't receive much help. Tell everyone here what you've tried. Put up some code.

Comment: So, what's not working.?

Comment: You already get a notification when it changes; why do you want to poll it every 10 sec?