# How can I know if the battery stop charging because of overheat, while the user run my application - Android?

Tags: android, batterymanager

I mean the charger is plugged in but it is not charging.

Is there any indication from the system about it?
I see it in "Waze" application when I get a message that the buttery stop charging because it is overheating.
my application is also a heavy one that causes the same problem sometimes,
so I want to know when it happens and announce a warning about it.

and another thing is -how can I tell that the battery stopped charging because of heat and not because it is 100% full?

Anyone please help me with this...

Comment: I hope you will get your answer here https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android

Comment: thank you all .. I'll try your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a simple broadcast receiver and can monitor the battery level and charging state or can use the following sticky intent. For example:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

And whenever you are on your desired batteryPct, you can notify user. For getting the battery temperature, you can also find information from `BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE` i-e

```
val temperature = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE)
```

For more details, see this [android reference](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#java)