# Can the charger is recognized as accessory in Android 2.3.4..?

Tags: android, usb, accessory

I want to recognize the charger through my application.

I implemented the Android Accessory API in my app, and installed in Samsung Galaxy S2.

But I am getting AccessoryList as null.

How to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charger is not an "accessory" per se, it is rather a state of the battery. Here's [a nice QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267161/how-to-detect-power-connected-state) on how to get notified about power connection state.

That your accessory list is empty could be due to some other issue. Please elaborate your question and provide some of your code, it is easier to help out when we know more.

Comment: I want to communicate with charger through USB OTG So, First I want to Identify the Charger as Accessory, Then I can use Streams to communicate with that.