# Creating app that requires external device to measure data

Tags: android

Is the Android platform conducive to building an app that requires a external device plugged into the power input of the cell phone in order to send data to the app it self to be measured and displayed?
I googled android & apple apps with external devices and did not find any for android only.
Thanks

Comment: it would be better to use bluetooth or NFC to communicate with an external device.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can check that both that the power is connected using ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and that the USB is connected using ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED of UsbManager:

See this question for how to test if power is connected:
[How to detect power connected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267161/how-to-detect-power-connected-state)

And this for a reference of how to use UsbManager:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can point you to the Android Accessory Development Kit...

http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html

There are two guides linked off of the first page, though they are a bit old and not liekly to be reflective of the new status of Android Studio > Eclipse [EDIT: this contains its own IDE, forgot that]